# Add Chip Select Hold Time to Beaglebone SPI

Tags: c#, beagleboneblack, spi

Is there a way to add a hold time to the CS in my library code so that I can define a set CS hold time over 740uS?

I'm using a Beaglebone Black with https://github.com/VegetableAvenger/BBBIOlib as my library for SPI operations. There is an inherent ~540us CS hold time from somewhere. I've tried adding physical code delays in my code, but it doesn't seem to effect this. I'm connecting it to a device that needs at least 750uS in order to transfer the data back to the Beaglebone. I've read over [2.5.1 Master Mode Timing Options](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/sprugp2a/sprugp2a.pdf) but can't seem to figure out how it would fit into this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "BBBiolib.h"
#include "BBBiolib_McSPI.h"
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* Argument define */

/* McSPI module have 4channel , but only pinout2 */
#define MCSPI_ARG_MODULE_COUNT  2
#define MCSPI_ARG_CHANNEL_COUNT 2

/* Device register mamory map */
#define MCSPI0_MMAP_ADDR    0x48030000
#define MCSPI1_MMAP_ADDR    0x481A0000
#define MCSPI_MMAP_LEN  0x1000

/* Device register offset */
#define MCSPI_SYSCONFIG 0x110
#define MCSPI_IRQENABLE 0x11c
#define MCSPI_IRQSTATUS 0x118
#define MCSPI_SYSSTATUS 0x114
#define MCSPI_SYST  0x124
#define MCSPI_MODULCTRL 0x128
#define MCSPI_CH0CONF   0x12C
#define MCSPI_CH0STAT   0x130
#define MCSPI_CH0CTRL   0x134
#define MCSPI_TX0   0x138
#define MCSPI_RX0   0x13C
#define MCSPI_XFERLEVEL 0x17C
#define MCSPI_DAFTX 0x180
#define MCSPI_DAFRX 0x1A0

/* offset between MCSPI_CH0CONF, MCSPI_CH1CONF, MCSPI_CH2CONF, MCSPI_CH3CONF */
#define MCSPI_CH_REG_OFFSET 0x14

#define CM_PER_SPI1_CLKCTRL_IDLEST_MASK (0x3 <<16)
#define MCSPI_GET_CHSTAT_EOT(a) ((a&0x04)>>2)
#define MCSPI_GET_CHSTAT_TXS(a) ((a&0x02)>>1)
#define MCSPI_GET_CHSTAT_RXS(a) (a&0x01)

#define MCSPI_GET_SYSSTATUS_RESETDONE(a)    (a&0x01)
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* struct definition */

#define McSPI_TxRx_Tx       0x01
#define McSPI_TxRx_Rx       0x02

struct BBBIO_McSPI_TxRx_struct
{
    unsigned int Tx ;
    unsigned int Rx ;
    unsigned int flag ;
};

#define McSPI_CH_ENABLE     0x01
#define McSPI_CH_DISABLE    0x02

/* McSPI channel strcut */
struct BBBIO_McSPI_CH_struct
{
    int status ;
    unsigned int Tx ;
    unsigned int Rx ;
    unsigned int flag ;
};

/* McSPI module struct */
struct BBBIO_McSPI_struct
{
    int CM_PER_enable ;
    struct BBBIO_McSPI_CH_struct CH[MCSPI_ARG_CHANNEL_COUNT];
};
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* Global Variable */
extern int memh;
extern volatile unsigned int *cm_per_addr ;

const unsigned int McSPI_AddressOffset[]={MCSPI0_MMAP_ADDR, MCSPI1_MMAP_ADDR};
volatile unsigned int *mcspi_ptr[MCSPI_ARG_CHANNEL_COUNT] ={NULL};

struct BBBIO_McSPI_struct McSPI_Module[MCSPI_ARG_MODULE_COUNT] ={0} ;
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
static inline void write_reg(volatile void *reg_base ,unsigned int offset ,unsigned int data)
{
    *((volatile unsigned int* )(reg_base+offset)) = data;
}
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
static inline unsigned int read_reg(volatile void *reg_base ,unsigned int offset)
{
    return *((volatile unsigned int* )(reg_base+offset));
}
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* McSPI init
 * iolib_init() will run this function automatically
 */
int BBBIO_McSPI_Init()
{
    int i ;
    if (memh == 0) {
        printf("BBBIO_McSPI_Init: memory not mapped?\n");
        return 0;
        }

    for (i = 0 ; i < MCSPI_ARG_MODULE_COUNT ; i++) {
        mcspi_ptr[i] = mmap(0, MCSPI_MMAP_LEN, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, memh, McSPI_AddressOffset[i]);
        if(mcspi_ptr[i] == MAP_FAILED) {
            printf("BBBIO_McSPI_Init: McSPI %d mmap failure!\n",i);
                    return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* McSPI module work function .
 *
 * BBBIO_McSPI_work provide Tx/Rx data from SPI module .
 *
 *  @param SPI_ID   : SPI module ID .
 *  @param chn  : channel ID , am335x provide channel 0~3 , but only  pin out  channel 0 and 1 .
 *  @param Tx_data  : Tx data ,ignore this arg in Rx only mode (0 as dummy).
 *  @param Rx_data  : Rx_data ,ignore this arg in Tx only mode , this arg could be NULL in TxRx mode , means Tx data without Rx data.
 *
 *  @return : 0 for error , 1 for success .
 */
int BBBIO_McSPI_work(unsigned int SPI_ID, unsigned int chn, unsigned int Tx_data, unsigned int *Rx_data)
{
    unsigned int chn_offset =0;
    unsigned int reg_value ;
    unsigned int Tx_flag =0;
    struct BBBIO_McSPI_CH_struct * chn_ptr = NULL;

    /* check CM_PER enable status, or it may caue "Bus error" signal message. */
    if(McSPI_Module[SPI_ID].CM_PER_enable) {
        if(McSPI_Module[SPI_ID].CH[chn].status & McSPI_CH_ENABLE) {
            chn_offset = chn * MCSPI_CH_REG_OFFSET ;
            chn_ptr = &McSPI_Module[SPI_ID].CH[chn];

            /* channel enable */
            write_reg(mcspi_ptr[SPI_ID], MCSPI_CH0CTRL + chn_offset, 1);

            /* set transform data */
            if(chn_ptr->flag & McSPI_TxRx_Tx) {
                chn_ptr->Tx = Tx_data ;
                write_reg(mcspi_ptr[SPI_ID], MCSPI_TX0 +chn_offset, chn_ptr->Tx);
            }
            else {  /* must set a dummy data in Tx reigster of receive only mode .*/
                write_reg(mcspi_ptr[SPI_ID], MCSPI_TX0 +chn_offset, 0);
            }

            /* Tx only waiting EOT
             * Rx only waiting RXS
             * TxRx waiting both EOT and RXS 
             * BBBio not support interrupt yet , using polling for the moment */
            reg_value =0;
            if(chn_ptr->flag & McSPI_TxRx_Tx) {
                while(!MCSPI_GET_CHSTAT_EOT(reg_value)) {
                    reg_value = read_reg(mcspi_ptr[SPI_ID], MCSPI_CH0STAT + chn_offset);
                    sched_yield();
                }
            }
            /* waiting for RXS */
            if(chn_ptr->flag & McSPI_TxRx_Rx) {
                while(!MCSPI_GET_CHSTAT_RXS(reg_value)) {
                    reg_value = read_reg(mcspi_ptr[SPI_ID], MCSPI_CH0STAT + chn_offset);
                    sched_yield();
                }
                /* copy receive data */
                if(Rx_data != NULL) {
                    chn_ptr->Rx = read_reg(mcspi_ptr[SPI_ID], MCSPI_RX0 + chn_offset);
                    *Rx_data = chn_ptr->Rx;
                }
            }

            /* channel disable */
            write_reg(mcspi_ptr[SPI_ID], MCSPI_CH0CTRL + chn_offset, 0);
        }
    }
    else {
#ifdef BBBIO_LIB_DBG
        printf("BBBIO_McSPI_work: McSPI %d CM_PER Clock Gating!\n",SPI_ID);
#endif
        return 0 ;
    }
    return 1 ;
}
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* McSPI module read function .
 *
 * BBBIO_McSPI_read provides Rx data from SPI module .
 *
 *  @param SPI_ID   : SPI module ID .
 *  @param chn  : channel ID, am335x provide channel 0~3, but only pin out channel 0 and 1 .
 *  @param Rx_data  : array to store data reads.
 *  @param Rx_count : number of data reads to perform.
 *
 *  @return : 0 for error , 1 for success .
 */
int BBBIO_McSPI_read(unsigned int SPI_ID, unsigned int chn, unsigned int *Rx_data, unsigned int Rx_count)
{
    unsigned int chn_offset =0;
    unsigned int reg_value;
    struct BBBIO_McSPI_CH_struct * chn_ptr = NULL;
    unsigned int ii;

    /* check CM_PER enable status, or it may caue "Bus error" signal message. */
    if(McSPI_Module[SPI_ID].CM_PER_enable) {
        if(McSPI_Module[SPI_ID].CH[chn].status & McSPI_CH_ENABLE) {
            chn_offset = chn * MCSPI_CH_REG_OFFSET ;
            chn_ptr = &McSPI_Module[SPI_ID].CH[chn];

            write_reg(mcspi_ptr[SPI_ID], MCSPI_CH0CTRL + chn_offset, 1);

            for (ii = 0; ii < Rx_count; ii++) {
                write_reg(mcspi_ptr[SPI_ID], MCSPI_TX0 +chn_offset, 0);
                reg_value =0;

                while(!MCSPI_GET_CHSTAT_RXS(reg_value)) {
                    reg_value = read_reg(mcspi_ptr[SPI_ID], MCSPI_CH0STAT + chn_offset);
                }

                reg_value = read_reg(mcspi_ptr[SPI_ID], MCSPI_RX0 + chn_offset);
                                Rx_data[ii] = reg_value;
            }

            write_reg(mcspi_ptr[SPI_ID], MCSPI_CH0CTRL + chn_offset, 0);
        }
    }
    else {
#ifdef BBBIO_LIB_DBG
        printf("BBBIO_McSPI_work: McSPI %d CM_PER Clock Gating!\n",SPI_ID);
#endif
        return 0 ;
    }
    return 1 ;
}
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* McSPI module channel control function .
 * 
 * BBBIO_McSPI_channel_ctrl provide channel configuration .
 *  @param SPI_ID   : SPI module ID (BBBIO_McSPI_SPI0 and BBBIO_McSPI_SPI1).
 *  @param chn  : channel ID , am335x provide channel 0~3 , but only  pin out  channel 0 and 1 .
 *  @param MS   : master or salve mode , BBBio lib only support Master mode now , slave mode setting is ignored (reserved for future).
 *  @param TRM  : TxRx mode ,support 3 mode :  TxRx mode / Rx Only / Tx Only.
 *  @param CLK_div  : Clock Divider , data range 0x00~0xFF , SPI module default clock is 48M Hz ,divid by 2^CLK_div .
 *  @param CLK_mode : please see file AM335x TRM , session "24.3.1.3.6 Polarity and Phase" , page 4537
 *  @param EPOL : SPI EN polarity , SPIEN is held high/low during the active state (BBBIO_McSPI_EN_ACT_HIGH/LOW). 
 *  @param DataDir  : Data pin status ,data0 Output data1 Input (BBBIO_McSPI_D0O_D1I) ,or data0 Input data1 Output (BBBIO_McSPI_D0I_D1O)
 *  @param WL   : word length per work , 4-bits ~ 32-bits, 
 *
 *  @return : 0 for error , 1 for success .
*/
int BBBIO_McSPI_channel_ctrl(unsigned int SPI_ID ,      /* SPI module ID , am335x have SPI1 and SPI0*/
                unsigned int channel ,      /* channel ID , channel 0~3 */
                unsigned int MS ,       /* MS           , maset or slave */
                unsigned int TRM ,      /* TRM          , Tx only / Rx only , TxRx */
                unsigned int CLK_div ,      /* Clock Divider    , default clock : 48M Hz */
                unsigned int CLKmode ,      /* POL/PHA      , Clock polarity */
                unsigned int EPOL ,         /* EPOL         , SPI EN polarity */
                unsigned int DataDir ,      /* IS/DPE1/DPE0     , data0 Output data1 Input ,or data0 Input data1 Output */
                unsigned int WL)        /* WL           , word length */
{
    int param_error=0;
    unsigned int chn_offset =channel * 0x14;

    if(!McSPI_Module[SPI_ID].CM_PER_enable) {
        printf("BBBIO_McSPI_channel_ctrl: McSPI %d CM_PER Clock Gated!\n",SPI_ID);
        param_error =1;
    }
    else if(MS == BBBIO_McSPI_Slave) {
        printf("BBBIO_McSPI_channel_ctrl: Sorry , BBBio only for master mode .\n");
        param_error =1;
    }
    else if(WL <4 || WL >32)
        param_error =1;

    /* check CM_PER enable status, or it may caue "Bus error" signal message. */
    if(!param_error) {
        /* disable channel */
        write_reg(mcspi_ptr[SPI_ID], MCSPI_CH0CTRL + chn_offset, 0);

        /* channel setting  */
        write_reg(mcspi_ptr[SPI_ID], MCSPI_MODULCTRL, MS << 2);
        write_reg(mcspi_ptr[SPI_ID], MCSPI_CH0CONF + chn_offset, (DataDir << 16 | TRM << 12 | (WL - 1) << 7 | EPOL << 6 | CLK_div << 2 | CLKmode));

        if(TRM != BBBIO_McSPI_Tx_Only) {
            McSPI_Module[SPI_ID].CH[channel].flag |= McSPI_TxRx_Rx ;
            McSPI_Module[SPI_ID].CH[channel].Rx =0;
        }
            if(TRM != BBBIO_McSPI_Rx_Only) {
                    McSPI_Module[SPI_ID].CH[channel].flag |= McSPI_TxRx_Tx ;
            McSPI_Module[SPI_ID].CH[channel].Tx =0;
        }
        McSPI_Module[SPI_ID].CH[channel].status |=McSPI_CH_ENABLE;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1 ;
}
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* Beaglebone Black , SPI Expansion Header Mode Check */
int BBBIO_McSPI_EP_check(unsigned int SPI_ID)
{
    unsigned int ret = 1;

    if(SPI_ID ==1) {
        /*SPI 1 cs 0~1*/
        if(!BBBIO_sys_pinmux_check(9, 19, BBBIO_PINMUX_MODE_4) &&
            !BBBIO_sys_pinmux_check(9, 20, BBBIO_PINMUX_MODE_4) &&
            !BBBIO_sys_pinmux_check(9, 28, BBBIO_PINMUX_MODE_3) &&
            !BBBIO_sys_pinmux_check(9, 42, BBBIO_PINMUX_MODE_2) ) {
            ret = 0;
        }

        /* SPI 1 Da0~1 , clk */
        if(!BBBIO_sys_pinmux_check(9, 29, BBBIO_PINMUX_MODE_3) &&
            !BBBIO_sys_pinmux_check(9, 30, BBBIO_PINMUX_MODE_3) &&
            !BBBIO_sys_pinmux_check(9, 31, BBBIO_PINMUX_MODE_3) &&
            !BBBIO_sys_pinmux_check(9, 42, BBBIO_PINMUX_MODE_4)) {
            ret =0;
        }
    }
    else {
        /* SPI 0 cs 0 */
        if(!BBBIO_sys_pinmux_check(9, 17, BBBIO_PINMUX_MODE_0)) {
                        ret = 0;
                }

                /* SPI 1 Da0~1 , clk */
                if(!BBBIO_sys_pinmux_check(9, 18, BBBIO_PINMUX_MODE_0) &&
                        !BBBIO_sys_pinmux_check(9, 21, BBBIO_PINMUX_MODE_0) &&
                        !BBBIO_sys_pinmux_check(9, 22, BBBIO_PINMUX_MODE_0)) {
                        ret =0;
                }
    }
    return ret ;
}
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* McSPI module Enable/Disable function
 *
 * In fact , clock control function . Disable means gating clock of spi module . 
 *  @param SPI_ID   : SPI module ID .
 *  @param enable   : enable/disable clock .
 *  @param idle : reserved for future.
 *
 *  @note :
 *      #define BBBIO_McSPI_Enable(a) BBBIO_McSPI_CLK_set(a,1,0)
 *      #define BBBIO_McSPI_Disable(a) BBBIO_McSPI_CLK_set(a,0,0)
 */

int BBBIO_McSPI_CLK_set(unsigned int SPI_ID ,int enable , int idle)
{
    const unsigned int CM_PER_McSPI[] = {BBBIO_CM_PER_SPI0_CLKCTRL, BBBIO_CM_PER_SPI1_CLKCTRL};

    if(SPI_ID > 1) {
        printf("BBBIO_McSPI_CLK_set: Unknow McSPI module ID : %d\n", SPI_ID);
        return 0 ;
    }

    /* pin mux check */
    if(!BBBIO_McSPI_EP_check(SPI_ID)) {
        printf("BBBIO_McSPI_CLK_set: No effect pin mux Detected of SPI-%d ,Please use EP_STATUS toolkit to check Pin mux mode\n", SPI_ID);
        return 0;
    }

    if(enable) {
        write_reg(cm_per_addr, CM_PER_McSPI[SPI_ID], 0x3 << 16 | 0x2);
        McSPI_Module[SPI_ID].CM_PER_enable = 1;
    }
    else {
        write_reg(cm_per_addr, CM_PER_McSPI[SPI_ID], 0);
        McSPI_Module[SPI_ID].CM_PER_enable = 0;
    }

    return 1 ;
}
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
void BBBIO_McSPI_Reset(unsigned int SPI_ID)
{
    unsigned int reg_value ;

    /* reset */
    write_reg(mcspi_ptr[SPI_ID], MCSPI_SYSCONFIG, 0x2 << 3 | 0x2);

    /* waiting reset finish */
    reg_value =0;
    while(!MCSPI_GET_SYSSTATUS_RESETDONE(reg_value)) {
        reg_value = read_reg(mcspi_ptr[SPI_ID] ,MCSPI_SYSSTATUS);
        sched_yield();
    }
#ifdef BBBIO_LIB_DBG
    printf("Reset Finish\n");
#endif
}
```